# “recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer)” and “upstream prematurely closed” errors on docker container with nginx

Tags: docker, nginx

I am setting up Outline VPN in a docker container on my DigitalOcean droplet, after configuring everything and trying to visit it on my website (outline.domain.com), it says “502 Bad Gateway”. I double checked all of my config files and they look correct. When I check my docker logs, I see these two errors coming up frequently:

`recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: {my ip}, server: {my domain}, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: {my droplet ip}`

`upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: {my ip}, server: {my domain}, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: {my droplet ip}`

What could be the issue and is there a fix?